# Cannot resolve method 'setFileDetector' in 'WebDriver' in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

As per this, https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/remote_webdriver/

I'm trying to set it up my Remote  webdriver with this option, by using webdrivermanager by bonigarcia and I use below code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector;

   //From a customzed method I get remote BrowserStack chrome instance.
   WebDriver driver= WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
   driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

But I get Cannot resolve method 'setFileDetector' in 'WebDriver. Please help.
[image]

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: Yes, the attached image's error comes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to typecast it, Did you try typecasting it to specific chromedriver ?

```
((ChromeDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

also you'd need to add :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger</artifactId>
      <version>0.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
      <version>1.34.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

in your `pom.xml`

Comment: Casting is often a sign of wrong API usage, and should be used as last resort. I would check for official Selenium guidance on this first.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `WebDriver`

Answer (score 1):

The best option to explore such error is to check public API docs, to make sure you use the right interface. [RemoveWebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) interface owns this method, [WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) is not.

So the solution would be to revise the construction of driver and make sure `RemoteWebDriver` instance is returned.

```
   // WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
   RemoteWebDriver driver = /* Use Selenium docs to construct the object */;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me to run the test in BrowserStack.

```
WebElement uploadFile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
((RemoteWebElement)uploadFile).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        upload_file.sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/resources/common/<Name of your file>.csv");
```